# SvelteKit - Deployment - @sveltejs/adapter-static not updating static paths in fallback page

Tags: typescript, svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit, svelte-component

I'm exploring SvelteKit for the first time, I built my simple first application and I'd like to deploy it to my Apache server as a static page

As far as I understood [adapter-static](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static) is the way to go, so I installed it and changed my `svelte.config.js` file to this:

```js
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    preprocess: preprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            paths: { base: "/PERSONAL_PATH" },
            fallback: 'index.html',
            precompress: false,
        })
    }
};

export default config;
```

**Now:**

The `npm run build` runs without any error, the thing is that when I check `index.html` all the dependencies of the page *(or the URLs of stylesheets and JS files if you will...)* have 2 problems as you can see below:

1. Have an absolute path, which makes it impossible to move the page's sources to any other location
2. Are not located in the folder `PERSONAL_PATH` where I'd like them to be

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.png" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <meta http-equiv="content-security-policy" content="">
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/start-25574c6c.js">
    <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/chunks/vendor-868763d8.js">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <script type="module" data-hydrate="45h">
        import { start } from "/_app/start-25574c6c.js";
        start({
            target: document.querySelector('[data-hydrate="45h"]').parentNode,
            paths: {"base":"","assets":""},
            session: {},
            route: true,
            spa: true,
            trailing_slash: "never",
            hydrate: null
        });
    </script></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Where am I getting it wrong? I've been trying to figure it out for hours but I'm stuck now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok I found out that I was setting the wrong parameters, so I fixed it and here's the working `svelte.config.js` (meaning that this configs actually set your static files to the custom path, that must be absolute):

```js
    import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
    import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

    /** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
    const config = {
        preprocess: preprocess(),

        kit: {
            // SET THE PATHS HERE
            paths: { assets: "", base: "/PERSONAL_PATH" },
            adapter: adapter({
                // NOT HERE!
                // paths: { base: "/PERSONAL_PATH" },
                fallback: 'index.html',
                precompress: false,
            })
        }
    };

    export default config;
```